# Types of Finite Clauses

Tags: clauses

I have been seeing a lot of "finite clauses" recently, all used in different ways. So I am here trying to clarify all the ways finite clauses can be used (or most of them).

I know a few finite clauses, like relative and content, but I don't know how much more there are.

Also, as a side question, I am wondering how the subordinate clause is acting here if you say
 "I will decide when we should go to the movies tomorrow"

Is the clause nominal, or a content clause, even though it starts with when? Also, is it even okay to call these clauses nominal (adverbial or adjectivial, too)?

Comment: As DW256 says, the main kinds of finite clauses are 'relative', 'comparative' and 'content', the latter being the default kind. I would strongly advise you to avoid using the terms nominal and adjectival to describe clauses.

Comment: BillJ Thank you. Do you think you may be able to answer my last question? It is of the sentence "I find it sad that he doesn't know the answer." Dw256 stated that "sad" was a predicative complement. I'm not sure why though. Is "that he doesn't know the answer" also acting as the technical direct object, and "it" is not the real direct object (dummy pronoun)?

Comment: No: _I find it sad that he doesn't know the answer_ is an internal complement extraposition construction, where dummy "it" appears as object and the subordinate content clause "that he doesn't know the answer" as extraposed object. Since "it" is direct object, "sad" would be objective predicative complement of "find".

Comment: Note that the non-extraposed version *_I find that he doesn't know the answer sad_ is ungrammatical by virtue of having the subordinate clause located between the verb and another complement.

Comment: Okay, thanks BillJ. So the direct object of the sentence is technically "it", not "that he doesn't know the answer"? And "that he doesn't know the answer" is an extraposed object? I appreciate the clarification. I also was pretty sure that "sad" was an object complement.

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thanks, much obliged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finite subordinate clauses, which I think is what you're asing about, are subclassified into:

i RELATIVE  *The one **who laughed** was Jill. / This is the book **I asked for***

ii COMPARATIVE *It cost more **than we expected***.  /  *He isn't as old as **I am***.

iii CONTENT *You said **that you liked her**.  / I wonder **what he wants***

The subordinate clause in your example is a content clause. Content clauses, just like main clauses have four clause types:

i DECLARATIVE *They say **that she is a good player**.*

ii CLOSED INTERROGATIVE *They didn't say **whether she is a good player**.*

iii OPEN INTERROGATIVE *I wonder**how good a player she is***.

iv EXCLAMATIVE *I'll tell them **what a good player she is***.

(CaGEL p62)

In the example given, *when we should go to the movies* is a open interrogative content clause similar to main clause *When should we go to the movies*. It is similar to saying that you'll decide the answer to that question,.

Comment: Thank you. Are there only 3 types of finite subordinate clauses: comparative, relative, and content? I thought there was a bit more. In that case, what type of clause would the finite subordinate clause be here: "I walked up to the building, which used to be a school, and knocked on the front door." I don't know which category that fits into.

Comment: Also, as a separate example, what type of clause would the subordinate clause be in this example: "I didn't know if he was going to write or type the paper."

Comment: The first is a supplementary relative. The second is a closed interrogative content clause.

Comment: Thank you. I saw this source a while back http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/complementtypes.pdf. It says that embeded questions are a type of content clause- are your examples 2, 3, and 4 just embedded questions?

Comment: Also, would that mean in this sentence, "It annoys me that she does that," it would be a "that clause"?

Comment: Terminology varies across different schools of analysis. According to the Oxford Dictionary of English Grammar, these constructions are best referred to as _subordinate interrogative clauses_. It also says that we can use the notion of _embedded question_ to refer to a question conveyed by a subordinate interrogative. The distiction is syntactic construction vs usage.

Comment: '_that_-clause' is not a very technical term. It usually refers to what are analysed as content clauses (CaGEL, OMEG) or nominal clauses (CGEL).

Comment: So you're saying my last example is also a subordinate interrogative clause? Edit: I just checked, wouldn't it be declarative content clause instead acting as a subject?Also thanks for the explanation

Comment: That's not what I said at all. _that she does that_ is clearly a declarative content clause. I have no idea how one would take that as containing a question.

Comment: You wording is just a bit confusing. I said that I figured out it must be a declarative content clause. But before I edited my comment, I thought it wasn't. I corrected myself. Either way, though, I'm happy for the explanation. If i'll be honest, I don't know how I thought it contained a question, either.

Comment: I have one last question, though. I saw this sentence on wikipedia, "I find it sad that he doesn't know the answer." It has a kind of a weird sentence structure, so what would be the simple sentence (simple subject and predicate). It's weird because it seems like "that he doesn't know the answer" is the direct object, but then sad is still there. Maybe "sad" is an object complement?

Comment: This is called extraposition with dummy _it_ (CaGEL p1408). The content clause is not allowed in object position, so it is extraposed (moved to the end) and dummy _it_ fills the object position. A rewording without extraposition might read something like: _What I find sad is that he doesn't know the answer_

Comment: I'm still a bit confused on the structure of the sentence. If "that he doesn't know the answer" is the subject, why in your reworded sentence, "what I find sad"  looks like the subject? Also is there even an object complement? What is the subject, complement/direct objects, verbs, and any other parts of the sentence? That's what I'm confused about. Which one is the matrix clause..

Comment: In your original sentence, the structure is [Subject - _I_][Predicatior - _find_][Object - _it_] [Predicative Complement - weird] [Extraposed content clause - _that he doesn't know the answer_]. In my rewording, the structure is [Subject - _What I find sad_ (this is a fused relative equivalent to _The thing that I find sad_)] [Predicator - _is_] [Complement(content clause) - _that he doesn't know the answer_]. The matrix clause in the first case is headed by _find_ and in the second by _is_.

Comment: Thanks DW256. I thought there may have been an object complement. On wikipedia, it did not say how "sad" was acting in the sentence (you said weird; I think you meant sad), but you say it is a predicative complement. What is the complement of, though? If "it" is the object (although isn't the extraposed content clause the real object?), then how is there a predicative complement, why isn't it predicative complement? Sorry for all the questions, by the way.

Comment: _find_ licenses predicative complement _sad_. The _predicand_ (the phrase of which something is predicated) here is dummy _it_ which has taken the place of the extraposed content clause, so in a roundabout way, the content clause is the predicand of _sad_. Predicative complements can be either subject-oriented (subjective) or object oriented (objective), in this case we have a object oriented predicative complement, or _objective PC_ for short. Again, terminology varies, the above analysis is using CaGEL's system.

Comment: Sorry DW256 for going back to an old discussion, but there is something I'm not sure about. In the sentences "She is a basketball player, while he is a baseball player" and "I ate my dinner as the sun went down." I feel like they do not fit into "comparative", which seems to be the only ""sensible" category. "Relative" and "content" don't seem to fit.

Comment: Also, I saw "as" used like this "Margaret Thatcher is now a life Baroness, as everyone knows." Thoughtco states that it is not called a relative, but instead a "comment clause." Does this mean comment clauses like the example above are also technically a "category"?